# Regarding the output of this do while loop program in C

Tags: c

I'm using the C compiler on CodeChef.com. I've written the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int scores[] = {23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28};
    int scoreslength = 0;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("%d \n", scores[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    while (i < scoreslength);
    return 0;
}
```

The output was `23`. I understood that as I gave the value of `scoreslength` to be `0` and the `do while` loop gets executed at least once because the condition, `while (i < scoreslength)` is given at the end of the loop. But when I gave the value of `scoreslength` to be `1`, the output was still `23`.

My question is, when the value of `scoreslength` is given to be `1` shouldn't the output be `23` and `24` as the loop gets executed first at `i = 0` and after incrementing gets executed again at `i = 1`?

Comment: The simplest way to verify your guess is to actually *try* it. And think about when and where `i` gets incremented. Lastly, using a proper IDE with a debugger that allows you to step through the code to see what happens is a big plus.

Comment: Head over to http://www.onlinegdb.com

Answer (score 1):

When scoreLength is given as 1, the loop executes for first time with i = 0. Inside the loop you are incrementing i = i + 1, which makes i = 1. So check your condition in the while loop. It says `i < scoreLength` which evaluates as false. So your loop executes only once.

Answer (score 0):

If scoreslength is 1, still only one pass on the loop will be before it exists.
If you set scoreslength  to two, the output will be 23 and 24.

Answer (score 0):

do while first execute the do then check the while to go next
step : 1

```
do
    {
        printf("%d \n", scores[i]); // here i = 0, output is 23
        i = i + 1;   // i becomes 1, so i = 1
    }
    while (i < scoreslength); // here 1 < 1 is false so can't execute further
    so the output is only 23
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int scores[] = {23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28};
    int scoreslength = 0;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("%d \n", scores[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    while (i <= scoreslength);

    return 0;
}
```